# Dummit 7.5.2. (Ring of fractions)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am doing exercise problem of chapter 7 of Dummit and Foote's Algebra.

The problem states

> **7.5.2**   Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $D$ be a nonempty subset of $R$ that is closed under multiplication. Prove that the ring of fractions $D^{-1}R$ is isomorphic to a subring of the quotient field of $R$. (hence is also an integral domain.).

In this problem, there is no restriction for $D$. For example, $D$ can contain $0$. But, when Dummit and Foote were constructing ring of fraction (Theorem 15), they specifically said $D$ should not contain $0$. Is it just wrong statement or I am missing something?

Comment: In the definition of "ring of fractions", the authors assumed $D$ does not contain $0$, does not contain any zero divisors, and closed under multiplication (assumptions in Theorem 15). So you can safely assume that $0\notin D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ D $ obviously cannot have zero  because these are the denominators of the quotient field you are constructing! They are using the notation of Theorem 15, I think.

Comment: In general $D$ may contain $0$. In that case $D^{-1}R$ will be the zero ring. It's a necessary and sufficient condition. But here you are right, the assumption is $0\notin D$.

Comment: You are right, but in the context of this particular book, they are likely referring to previously used notation.